# ¿Como dividir el espacio equitativamente y repartirlo a 5 columnas en bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4, flexbox

Actualmente estoy usando la clase row, debo tener 5 columnas, necesito que las 5 columnas ocupen todo el espacio, pero que todas tengan el mismo ancho. el espacio que resta lo intente repartir usando flex-grow: 1 con la clase que ya provee bootstrap pero no funciona...

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-2 flex-xl-grow-1" style="background-color: orange">
                    hello
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-2 flex-xl-grow-1" style="background-color: orange">
                    hello
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-2 flex-xl-grow-1" style="background-color: orange">
                    hello
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-2 flex-xl-grow-1" style="background-color: orange">
                    hello
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-2 flex-xl-grow-1" style="background-color: orange">
                    hello
                </div>
            </div>
```

Alguien sabe ¿porque? no se si sea porque el `width` en bootstrap se esta asignando con `flex-basis` en lugar de con `width`, no se si tenga que ver...

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, yo igual recién comienzo en este mundo. Entiendo que solo necesitas las 5 columnas centradas usando todo el ancho. Para eso, en este ejemplo no uso flex.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk"
crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Ayudando a un amigo</title>

    <style>
      .row .col {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 100%;
      }


    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col">
          1 of 5
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          2 of 5
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          3 of 5
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          4 of 5
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          5 of 5
        </div>
      
    </div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 5
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 5
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      3 of 5
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      4 of 5
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      5 of 5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Grid system

- Gracias a `flexbox`, **las columnas sin ancho especificado se ordenaran automáticamente en columnas del mismo ancho**. Por ejemplo, cuatro instancias de `col-sm` tendrá cada una de forma automática un ancho equivalente a la cuarta parte del tamaño de la pantalla en los `breakpoint` *small* hacia arriba.
- Las clases columnas (`col`) **indican el numero de columnas que te gustaría usar de las 12 que hay por cada renglón** (`row`). De manera que, si quieres usar 3 columnas que tengan el mismo ancho, puedes usar `col-4`.
- Los anchos de las columnas están configurados en porcentajes, por lo que siempre se comportaran de forma *fluida* y su tamaño es relativo al **elemento padre**
- Para hacer la *cuadrícula* `responsiva`, hay cinco `breakpoints`:

  1. Todos los `breakpoints` (*extra small* = `col`).
  2. *small* (`col-sm`).
  3. *medium* (`col-md`).
  4. *large* (`col-lg`).
  5. *extra large* (`col-xl`).
- Los `breakpoints` del `grid` en el ancho mínimo de las `media queries`, lo que significa que se aplican al `breakpoint`especificado y a todos sus superiores. Por ejemplo `col-sm-4` se aplica a *small, medium, large y extra large*, pero no se aplica al `breakpoint` *extra small*
  [bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid)

---

Con esos puntos aclarados para que tus columnas tengan el mismo ancho tanto en las pantallas más pequeñas como en las de mayor tamaño, solo es necesario cambiar la clase `col-xl-2` por `col` ya que la primera nos dice que las columnas tendrán un ancho de 2 columnas en los dispositivos *extra large* y en las demás será de 12.
La clase `flex-xl-grow-1` no se que uso tenga pero supongo que influye en el comportamiento de los elementos hijo.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col" style="background-color: orange">
                    hello
                </div>
                <div class="col" style="background-color: orange">
                    hello
                </div>
                <div class="col" style="background-color: orange">
                    hello
                </div>
                <div class="col" style="background-color: orange">
                    hello
                </div>
                <div class="col" style="background-color: orange">
                    hello
                </div>
            </div>
```